# How to update a Python string in a for loop?

Tags: python, string, discord, discord.py

I am building a Discord bot using the `discord.py` library. The library uses the `on_message(ctx)` event to let us modify a message if we want to. What I would like to do is to remove the formatting and replace the user mentions with the Discord names. The text of the message looks like this:

```
<@!34565734654367046435>  <@!34565734645354367046435> are you here?
```

In the `ctx` variable I can get the mentions as `User` objects from `ctx.mentions` and I can get the **NAME** and the **ID** of each mentioned user.

I'd like to replace the `<@!34565734654367046435>` with the name of the user. The result to be something like:

```
Name1 Name2 are you here?
```

This is what I have so far but it does not seem to work.

```
remove_formatting = utils.remove_markdown(context.content)
print(remove_formatting) # prints the very first code styled line in this question
for member in context.mentions:
   remove_formatting.replace(f'<@!{member.id}>', member.name)
```

If I print the `member.id` and the `member.name` without doing anything else, I get the expected values. How do I update the string in this for loop?

Comment: What is the actual result you're getting? Have you printed `remove_formatting` to ensure it is what you expect before you do the replace?

Comment: yes it is the very first code styled line: <@!34565734654367046435>  <@!34565734645354367046435> are you here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace` function returns a new string, it doesn't edit the existing string in place.  If you edit your loop to:

```py
remove_formatting = utils.remove_markdown(context.content)
for member in context.mentions:
   remove_formatting = remove_formatting.replace(f'<@!{member.id}>', member.name)
```

it should work.

Comment: yes it did work. it is almost identical with PHP :) thanks

Comment: yes it needs some time until i am able to